# Why when i try to save the ids obtained from the onRowSelectionModelChange my DataGrid stops working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm writing a React App using Material UI and I want to dinamically render some buttons based on how many rows are selected using the default checkbox of my data grid. To do so, I'm passing the rows selected to a function handler in the parent component.

```
onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
    let selected = props.customers.filter((entry) => { return ids.includes(entry.id_customer) })
    console.log(selected)
    // props.handlerSelectionRow(selected)
}}
```

The `console.log` works perfectly, but if i uncomment the `props.handler`, all the checks on the checkbox disappear and the data grid stops showing checkmarks graphically when clicked. Instead of returning an array that dinamically fills itself with the ids of the selected rows, it always returns an array of a single element with the last id selected.

This is my entire DataGrid Component:

```
<DataGrid
    localeText={itIT.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
    disableColumnMenu
    columns={ columns }
    rows={ props.orders }
    initialState={{
        pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
                pageSize: 5,
            }
        }
    }}
    pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
    checkboxSelection
    disableRowSelectionOnClick
    onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
        let selected = props.customers.filter((entry) => { return ids.includes(entry.id_customer) })
        console.log(selected)
        // props.handlerSelectionRow(selected)
    }}
    onCellClick={ handleCellClick }
    getRowId={(row) => row.id_order}
    slots={{ 
        toolbar: GridToolbar 
    }}
    slotProps={{
        toolbar: {
            printOptions: { disableToolbarButton: true }
        }
    }}
/>
```

This is the handler in the parent component:

```
const handlerSelectionRow = (rows) => setSelectedTableRows(rows);
```

Comment: onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {... }
Here ids are order ids, but you are comparing it with customer id.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMing for the clarification, unfortunately my problem might be from something else. Even saving the ids directly in a new state like this (or in a simple variable) breaks the datagrid checkbox.
`const [state, setState ] = useState([])
onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => { setState(ids) }}`